# Paperclip: why, despite the reduction of quality, the size of an image does not change much?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to reduce the size (in byte) of an uploading image using the Paperclip plugin/gem. I need that because I would like to improve the performance related to the loading time of web pages in my application.

At this time in my model file I have:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :styles      => {
      :small    => ["250x250#", :jpg] 
  }
  :convert_options => { :small => '-quality 40' }
```

That will convert images in to the `.jpg` format, set dimensions and reduce the quality to 40 (this value is just for testing).

However, what I noticed is that, despite the reduction of quality, the size of the file does not change much. For instance I report the size of an image with and without using the option `:convert_options => { :small => '-quality 40' }`:

```
# Without using the 'convert_options'
Image size: 57.35 kB (58730 bytes)

# Using the 'convert_options'
Image size: 55.25 kB (56576 bytes)
```

**Why the difference is so little? What is the best practice to reduce the size without losing much quality?**

---

**UPDATE**: Maybe, as @Matt Gibson said commenting this question, for the compression it is important also the "how an image *look* like" (e.g. photographic). It seems that compression varies from picture to picture based on backgrounds, number of colors, ... in the image.

Comment: What does your image _look_ like? Is it really suitable for JPEG compression, i.e. photographic?

Comment: @user502052 Re your update: well, at least you're using the right algorithm (JPEG is almost always better for photographs than GIF or PNG, for example), but as you observe, JPEG compression varies quite a lot depending on the input photograph. A simple picture will compress far better than a complex picture. Also, it depends what kind of image you're compressing in the first place -- reencoding a JPEG as a smaller JPEG won't gain you a lot. The place JPEG really impresses is in how well it compresses original, *uncompressed* photographic images compared to other algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options should work fine, maybe your image just doesn't compress that well. Try to playing around with the `convert` tool on the command tool ([see docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)) to see what helps. Also, [it appears](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Usage) that paperclip can now take a `:quality` option directly.

Answer (score 3):

You say you want to improve the **load time** of your website so let me offer an alternate solution. Why not offload your images to a service like [amazon s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (simple storage system) so they can serve up your images for you? And to really speed things up you can use a content delivery service like [amazon cloud front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). This will probably speed up your site much more than lowering the image quality. Another benefit is that it'll be pretty cheap when you start out (most likely free) and you'll be able to scale easily in the future if you end up needing that.

Answer (score 1):

It's could be a bug of paperclip when setting convert_options for a style (a.e. :small) , look at this [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issuesearch?state=open&q=convert#issue/342)